# The Install button is missing when trying to upgrade a app from a deb file using the Ubuntu Software GUI after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-center, deb

I have a Dell XPS 13 7390 that came with Ubuntu 18.04. It recently prompted me to upgrade to 20.04, so I did.

Some of my software, checks for updates when it starts, one example is *DBeaver*. I have found if I download a deb file for applications that existed before the upgrade, the "Ubuntu Software" GUI opens but with no <kbd>install</kbd> button, it only has a <kbd>Remove</kbd> button:

[image]

Before the upgrade, I would install new versions of my applications updates using a <kbd>Install</kbd> button in the "Ubuntu Software" GUI.

Anyone know a way to fix this and get back the <kbd>Install</kbd> button.

Notes:

- I tried removing the application and re-installing. This doesn't fix it, the next update is also missing the <kbd>Install</kbd> button, so updating is hard.
- I know I could try a different way of installing, e.g. `dpkg` on the CLI but I want to solve this problem without a workaround.

Comment: There's no `Install` button because it's already installed, and from the DBeaver website it looks like version 7.2.4 is the latest version.

Comment: Thanks @CarlH - it's true what you said. The behavour is different after the upgrade though. I'll keep an eye open to see if I can clarify things more clearly next time there is a app update to install.
It seems what happens after I double-click a new deb is that the Ubuntu Software pops up with no Install button, but the "Software Updater" contains the upgrade if I check it, but it doesn't show until I check for updates. I have changed my settings to "display immediately" rather than "display weekly". I'll see if that helps.

Comment: You don't need to be downloading and clicking deb files. If you install something with the Ubuntu Software tool then it will take care of updates itself.  You might find 'display immediately' will quickly get annoying, but daily should be tolerable.   :-)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that once you install a deb file, it subscribes to updates for that app. Thanks @CarlH.  I still think something is fishy though - next time it happens I'll pay super close attention and report back.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessarily so, that the software app updates automatically.

For instance, the RStudio app from Posit will not.

It's no bigger a problem than downloading the deb file and running dpkg, but for the non-tech-savvy-point-and-click user, the software gui is not much help, in that situation.